# Hibernate Postgres Slow Insert

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jhipster

I try to insert data into Postgres using JPA/Hibernate/Postgres. 
The data is parsed from a CSV File and then should be saved into a postgres database. The code that persists the data looks as follows:

```
        @Autowired
    KundeRepository repo;
    @Transactional
    public void safe(Kunde kd) {
        repo.save(kd);
    } 
 public void safeAll(Iterable<Kunde> kt) {
        repo.save(kt);
        repo.flush();
    }
```

The entity look as follows

```
public class account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    Kunde kunde;
    @OneToMany
    List<TransaktionsGruppe> gruppen;


       @Entity
@Table(name = "kunde")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Kunde implements Serializable {

    public static final String kundennummerKey = "KUNDENNUMMER";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String id;  
    @OneToMany
    List<Account> accounts;



    @Entity
@Table(name = "transaktionsgruppe")
public class Transaktionsgruppe  implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    Account acc;

    private String bezeichnung;
```

When I now pass a Collection to the safeAll method the inserts are really slow. Especially it seems to call the hibernate sequence for every insert. Is there a way to speed things up?

My configuration looks as follows:

```
datasource:
       type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
       url: dburl
       username: user
       password: pw
       hikari:
         validation-timeout: 10000
         health-check-properties: {"connectivityCheckTimeoutMs","1000"}
jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
        hibernate.jdbc.batch.size: 100
        hibernate.order_inserts: true+
```

Currently show-sql is enabled. It is about 60000 Entities overall and it takes more than 20 Minutes. the entitties are rather small in size

Comment: How much slow? How many entities? At which level have you set `@Transactional` annotation? Have you tried show-sql: false? Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: When doing ETL (Extract, Transform and Load) on PostgreSQL, ORMs will cause a significant speed reduction. The fastest way to get your data in, is to serialize it back to CSV, and insert it into tables using the `COPY` command. Nothing is faster on Postgresql than COPY.

Comment: I added some more detail. It is not an option to use the copy comand because i have split the row into various tables.

Comment: How slow then ?

Comment: It looks like you have done what Vlad describes in his blog - https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/ Where are your `Transaction` boundaries? If each insert is run in its own transaction then it will be slow and your settings for batches won't have any effect. What is happening inside `KundeRepository`?

Comment: I also see you use HikariCP for connection pooling, have you tried this with the plain jdbc driver first? Are you using/forcing the use of `PreparedStatements`, are they being cached? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764142/does-hibernate-use-preparedstatement-by-default

Comment: By `safe` you mean `save` ?

Comment: How does your entity Kunde looks like?

Comment: the Kunde is straightforward a basically similar to the Kunde. I forget the following thins :

Answer (score 0):

Your `safeAll()` method is not annotated with `@Transactional` so Spring opens and closes a transaction for each item of your list. By annotating it, Spring will open and close one single transaction for the whole list.